# How to set constant proportions in canvas?

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

How to set constant proportions in canvas(QwtPlotCanvas)?

I am using Qt 4.7.3 and Qwt 6.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p->axisScaleDraw()->setMinimumExtent(80);
```